# Динамическая подгрузка мета тегов

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Есть сайт с записями. Пользователю предлагаеться поделиться записью в Фейсбук.
Вся логика сайта на клиенте(динамически подгружаеться через ajax).
Теги для фейсбука вставляю через `$("meta[name=pt]").attr('content',title);`
Но бот для парсинга фейсбук их не видит(наверное он не заботает с js).

Самый простой выход - подгружать часть данных черех php, но это мне не подходит.

Вопрос. Существут какие то очень продвинутые способы решения этой проблемы?